# How do I start a new powershell instance and run commands in it?

Tags: c#, powershell

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I need a user to automatically run a powershell script when he logs into the computer, have the script start an Elevated Powershell Prompt(the same as if the user could click on Run Powershell as Administrator) and then have it run some commands in the new Powershell Object, then close the new Powershell object.

This function currently will create and run a new Powershell object in Elevated mode.

```
function Set-Elevation
{
   # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
   $newProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "powershell";
   # Indicate that the process should be elevated
   $newProcess.Verb = "runas";
   # Start the new process
   [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess) | Out-Null
}
```

However, how would I get it to run new commands in there? And how would I close the object afterward?

Any tips on the syntax would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built-in Start-Process command:

```
function IsAdministrator
{
    $Identity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    $Principal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($Identity)
    $Principal.IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
}

function IsUacEnabled
{
    (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLua -ne 0
}

#
# Main script
#
if (!(IsAdministrator))
{
    if (IsUacEnabled)
    {
        [string[]]$argList = @('-NoProfile', '-NoExit', '-File', $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
        $argList += $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | Foreach {"-$($_.Key)", "$($_.Value)"}
        $argList += $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
        Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -WorkingDirectory $pwd -ArgumentList $argList 
        return
    }
    else
    {
        # Log an error, do nothing or Start-Process -Credentials <admin_creds>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use this self elevating script, you can run your commands right in the PS1 without any hassle.

```
$WID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
$WIP=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($WID);
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator;
If ($WIP.IsInRole($adminRole)){
}else {
  $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo 'PowerShell';
  $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
  $newProcess.Verb = 'runas'
  [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);Write-Host 'Prompting for Elevation'
  exit
}

Write-Host 'ElevatedCodeRunsHere';
Write-Host 'Press any key to continue...'
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')
```

Comment: Could you break up your lines a little, its kinda hard to read with multiple commands all on one line.

Comment: What's up with all the semicolon line termination and the empty `if` block? Surely this would be more readable (or at least reduce horizontal scrolling) if you'd Put each line on its own line.

Comment: Exit doesn't seem to work right for me, either. Writing a ps1 script with just one command: "exit" doesn't close the session when invoked. It seems to only end the script - but how would I close the entire previous object?

Comment: actually with this script you won't need a previous object, put this snip in the previous object and it will elevate itself.

Comment: I tried the code but it seems to fail - I tried to execute it with the argument of Get-ChildItem, but it indicates it as an invalid argument list. Where is $pwd passed into it as well?