# How to copy certain files to startup folder while installing Windows 8.1 apps?

Tags: batch-file, powershell, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, startup

I am developing a `WebView` based Windows 8.1 app, which is an enterprise app, not to be uploaded on store. App will be installed on single user account. App is sort of kiosk app. Currently there's no provision to delete the cache of `WebView`. Though cache is stored at `%localappdata%\Packages\PACKAGE_ID\AC\INetCache` location. So I've created a batch script to delete the files in it. Now I want to copy that batch file in startup folder so each time when device boots the cache is cleared. I am thinking to copy the file when app package is being installed via Powershell. I know the cmdlet of copying file but I don't know where should I write the copy command in `Add-AppDevPackage.ps1` script. Moreover it requires elevation to copy the file, so I may need to prompt for elevation. Can anyone help me to achieve what I want to?

Comment: Are you asking where the start up location for user is?

Comment: No, in .ps1 file of app installation where should I write the code for copy-paste.

Comment: How about posting your code? The purely verbal description is rather vague and leaves a lot to interpretation...and how can someone tell you where in the script to put something without seeing the script?

Comment: Here is a self elevating snip, it prompts for UAC when running.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642502/how-do-i-start-a-new-powershell-instance-and-run-commands-in-it/20642785#20642785

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't you use the Run key from the registry and point to the current location of your script without the need for admin rights.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx